# Joda Time: Why does Month value default to Jan regardless of date input?

Tags: java, jodatime

This is my first time using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). Why does the month default to January? It doesn't matter what month values i enter as date including (1-12) or (Jan-Dec). All default to January.

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy/MM/DD HH:mm:ss");
DateTime issuedTimeStamp = fmt.parseDateTime("2014/04/30 08:23:36");

System.out.println("Issued: " + issuedTimeStamp.toString()); 
//above prints `2014-01-30T08:23:36.000-05:00`
```

Ive checked my pattern which seems right. Where am i going wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're using `DD` in your format string, which means "day of year". So after parsing the month as April, you're then going to the 30th day of the year, which is in January... You want `dd`, for "day of month".

When in doubt, if a format string doesn't do what you expect:

- Check every format specifier against the documentation
- Check that you're escaping everything you should
- Try *formatting* a hard-coded value (ideally similar to one that's failing to parse)

Comment: Arg! Thank you. Clearly I didn't review the pattern very well. Thank you for the quick response! Its an honor to have you answer my question. :-D